# Python Pandas Pivot Table Calculations

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the mean values for each row in this Python Pandas Pivot table that I have created.

I also want to add the sum of each year at the bottom of the pivot table.

The last step I want to do is to take the average value for each month calculated above and divide it with the total average in order to get the average distribution per year.

```
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 31)

libor = web.DataReader('USD1MTD156N', 'fred', start, end) # Reading the data
libor = libor.dropna(axis=0, how= 'any') # Dropping the NAN values
libor = libor.resample('M').mean() # Calculating the mean value per date
libor['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(libor.index).month # Adding month value after each 
libor['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(libor.index).year # Adding month value after each 

pivot = libor.pivot(index='Month',columns='Year',values='USD1MTD156N')
print pivot
```

Any suggestions how to proceed? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want (This is on python3 - I think only the print command is different in this script):

```
# Mean of each row
ave_month = pivot.mean(1)
#sum of each year at the bottom of the pivot table.
sum_year = pivot.sum(0)
# average distribution per year.
ave_year = sum_year/sum_year.mean()
print(ave_month, '\n', sum_year, '\n', ave_year)
Month
1     0.324729
2     0.321348
3     0.342014
4     0.345907
5     0.345993
6     0.369418
7     0.382524
8     0.389976
9     0.392838
10    0.392425
11    0.406292
12    0.482017
dtype: float64 
 Year
2011     2.792864
2012     2.835645
2013     2.261839
2014     1.860015
2015     2.407864
2016     5.953718
2017    13.356432
dtype: float64 
 Year
2011    0.621260
2012    0.630777
2013    0.503136
2014    0.413752
2015    0.535619
2016    1.324378
2017    2.971079
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you Jorge. That helped a lot.

Comment: I added this to the script to include it in the pivot table. The only thing missing is that i would like to append the totals by the end of the pivot table.                                                                                                          ave_month = pivot.mean(1)
sum_year = pivot.sum(0)

pivot['Monthly_Average'] = ave_month # Add average column in pivot table
pivot['Seasonality'] = ave_month / ave_month.sum() # Add Seasonality column in pivot table

Comment: tried this: pivot = pivot.append(pivot.agg('sum'), ignore_index= True) , but it messes up my index

Answer (score 1):

I would use pivot_table over pivot, and then use the aggfunc parameter.

```
pivot = libor.pivot(index='Month',columns='Year',values='USD1MTD156N')
```

would be

```
import numpy as np
pivot = libor.pivot_table(index='Month',columns='Year',values='USD1MTD156N', aggfunc=np.mean)
```

YOu should be able to drop the resample statement also if I'm not mistaken

A link ot the docs:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html